# Nested flex scroll growing out of div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent with 2 divs, one containing a very long div :

```css
.parent {
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.b {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.b_child {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">hello</div>
  <div class="b"><div class="b_child">Very long div</div></div>
  <div class="c">bottom</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smf8y0L7/

As you can see, the .b_child is overflowing and growing out of b. If I set the scroll to .b instead it works as expected, but I want my flex child's child to scroll.

Comment: `I want my flex child's child to scroll.` That's exactly what's happening when you move the scroll to `.b` I don't understand

Comment: height: 100%; to child and min-height:0 to .b

Comment: @Vinz243 have you tried the code?

Comment: @ZohirSalak not really, on the xample i added some text between b and b_child. I don't want `***some toolbar***` to scroll

Comment: @TemaniAfif seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get the job done:

```
.b_child {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `overflow: auto` on `.b_child`

```css
.parent {
  height: 150px;  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font: .9rem/1.5 Arial;
}

.b {
  flex: 1 1  auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b_child {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">hello</div>
  <div class="b">
     <div class="b_child">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque egestas neque purus, sit amet vestibulum nisl fermentum non. Integer blandit suscipit dapibus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent et ligula vel dolor pulvinar laoreet a nec leo. Praesent enim lorem, consectetur ac leo quis, auctor vestibulum nunc. Nam hendrerit cursus tortor, eget congue felis porta id. Suspendisse rutrum ex sed turpis ultrices, vel molestie urna pharetra. Aenean eget mi sit amet nisi commodo condimentum non lobortis velit. Suspendisse quis posuere metus, faucibus ullamcorper orci. Pellentesque lobortis augue nec mauris pharetra scelerisque. Donec eget metus nunc. Phasellus ultrices in nibh ut suscipit. Nam semper elit purus, a dignissim purus bibendum eu. Vestibulum vel venenatis dui, ac fringilla neque. Nulla a urna risus. Nulla varius diam sed arcu hendrerit, non fermentum turpis porttitor. Aenean eget vehicula ligula. Vivamus dignissim ipsum non mollis pulvinar. Etiam varius massa eget ullamcorper mattis. Etiam commodo dui sem, eu tincidunt arcu tristique sit amet. Cras sit amet fringilla quam. Suspendisse sollicitudin porttitor nisi, quis feugiat metus scelerisque eu. Sed tempus justo quis arcu lobortis vulputate. Sed ut semper ex. In et ex arcu. Nam ex ante, viverra sit amet est malesuada, pharetra sollicitudin eros. Nullam at sagittis dui. Nunc laoreet tellus non ipsum pretium, a accumsan metus pulvinar.
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">bottom</div>
</div>
```